# Spliting column by multiple delimiters (keeping them) and into unequal number of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, split, tidyr

lets say I have a dataframe like this (simplified, similar version of my problem) :

```
ID <- c(1,2,3)
value <- c("1+4-3", "2+7-6+4-3", "-1+3")
df <- data.frame(ID, value)

ID  value
1   1+4-3
2   2+7-6+4-3
3   -1+3
```

I need to split the `value` column into multiple columns by multiple delimiters (`+` and `-`), while keeping the delimiter in the separate columns.

The resulting dataframe would should like this:

```
ID  x1  x2  x3  x4  x5   x6   x7   x8   x9
1   1   +   4   -   3    <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2   2   +   7   -   6    +    4    -    3
3   -   1   +   3   <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

In addition, I don't know how many resulting columns I would need (might not be 9 like in the example, but 50).

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you need them as mutliple columns?  I might consider making them vectors of strings within a single list column, so you don't need the variable width?

Comment: If I add a new observation ID=3 and value = "-1-2-3" (the 1st number is negative), what's the expected output?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Multiple columns would be preferable. But would be glad for any solution that I could later adjust for my purpose.

Comment: @DarrenTsai perfect question, that would be "-" "1" "-" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach:

```
ID <- c(1,2,3)
value <- c("1+4-3","2+7-6+4-3","25+110/2*214")
# added example 3 to show effect on numbers with >1 digit
df <- data.frame(ID,value)

df |> dplyr::mutate(
  X = lapply(value, \(x) {
    # split by word/nonword boundaries
    y <- stringr::str_split(x, pattern = "\\b", simplify = TRUE)
    # drop the empty first and last strings
    y[nzchar(y)]
  })) |> tidyr::unnest_wider(X, names_sep = "")
```

gives

```
# A tibble: 3 × 11
     ID value        X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9   
  <dbl> <chr>        <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 1+4-3        1     +     4     -     3     NA    NA    NA    NA   
2     2 2+7-6+4-3    2     +     7     -     6     +     4     -     3    
3     3 25+110/2*214 25    +     110   /     2     *     214   NA    NA
```

If you remove the pipe to `unnest_wider` you get this instead, which IMO may be tidyer in some ways:

```
  ID        value                         X
1  1        1+4-3             1, +, 4, -, 3
2  2    2+7-6+4-3 2, +, 7, -, 6, +, 4, -, 3
3  3 25+110/2*214  25, +, 110, /, 2, *, 214
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `separate_wider_delim()` from `tidyr`:

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_wider_delim(value,
                       delim = stringr::regex("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)"),
                       too_few = "align_start",
                       names_sep = '',
                       names_repair = ~ sub("value", "X", .x))

# # A tibble: 3 × 10
#      ID X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9   
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 1     +     4     -     3     NA    NA    NA    NA   
# 2     2 2     +     7     -     6     +     4     -     3    
# 3     3 -     1     +     3     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: I think this is the cleanest non-base answer so far.

Answer (score 2):

If you have numbers consisting of `digits` only, you can try

```
df %>%
  mutate(value = str_extract_all(value, "\\d+|\\D")) %>%
  unnest(value) %>%
  mutate(name = seq_len(n()), .by = ID) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_prefix = "X")
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 2 × 10
     ID X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 1     +     4     -     3     NA    NA    NA    NA
2     2 2     +     7     -     6     +     4     -     3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  separate_longer_delim(cols = value, delim = regex("(?=\\+|-)")) |> 
  separate_longer_position(cols = value, width = 1) |> 
  mutate(pos = row_number(), .by = ID) |> 
  pivot_wider(values_from = value,
              names_from = "pos",
              names_prefix = "X")

# A tibble: 3 × 10
     ID X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9   
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 1     +     4     -     3     NA    NA    NA    NA   
2     2 2     +     7     -     6     +     4     -     3    
3     3 -     1     +     3     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: Note that this does not handle numbers with more than one digit, which may or may not be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

[Edited to work with numbers with more than one digit]

Using just r-base:

```r
# Example data
ID <- c(1,2)
value <- c("1+4-3","2+72-6+42-3")
df <- data.frame(ID,value)

# Function to do custom split
mysplit <- function(x){
  a <-gregexpr('[0-9]+',x)
  b <- gregexpr('[+-]{1}',x)
  res <- unlist(c(regmatches(x,a),regmatches(x,b)))
  res[order(unlist(c(a,b)))]
}

# split and fill with NAs
s <- sapply(df$value,mysplit)
mlength <- max(sapply(s,length))
s <- sapply(s, function(x) c(x,rep(NA,mlength - length(x))))

# Return dataframe
data.frame(ID = df$ID,t(s))

            ID X1 X2 X3 X4 X5   X6   X7   X8   X9
1+4-3        1  1  +  4  -  3 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2+72-6+42-3  2  2  + 72  -  6    +   42    -    3
```

EDIT

Comment: Note that this solution cannot cope with numbers with more than one digit, if that is relevant (unclear from OP).

Comment: I haven't realized. Now I think it works